# for loop executed but list of schools are not showing

Tags: django-views

As i understand for loop is executing three times as the it should(as per three records). but why does not taking the values from records ?

```
    #school_list.html
        <h2>List of School Names</h2>
        {% for everyschool in object_list %}
        <p>School info :{{school.schoolName}} {{ school.controller }} {{ school.email }} </p>
        {% endfor %}





   #views.py
        from django.shortcuts import render
        from django.views.generic import View,TemplateView, ListView
        from . import models
        # Create your views here.
        class SchoolListView(ListView):
             model = models.School
```

**I have three school records as

Django administration
WELCOME, GAGAN. VIEW SITE / CHANGE PASSWORD / LOG OUT
Home › Myapp › Schools
Select school to change
ADD SCHOOL
Action:  Go 0 of 3 selected

SCHOOL
    another school
    nd school
    GHS Hill Kalan
3 schools

OUTPUT ON BROWSER

List of School Names
School info :

School info :

School info :**

Comment: The iterator object is `everyschool`, not `school`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iterator in your template is `everyschool`, but you use `school` in you template. You should rename either the iterator, or the variable used in your template:

```
{% for school in object_list %}
<p>School info :{{ school.schoolName }} {{ school.controller }} {{ school.email }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```